# uitableview cell cellForRowAtindexPath fetch first letter pick from name in swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom cell for my UITableView, I will show first characters of the item name [like this"below image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7NqH.png)

so my question is how to create it how to fetch first letter pick from name data fetch via json.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectTabTableViewCell
   cell.colorViewOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    let projectLst = projectList[indexPath.row]



    let str = projectLst.NameEN



    print(str?.characters.first?.description ?? "");
    projectNameFirst = [str?.characters.first?.description ?? ""]
    print(projectNameFirst)
    cell.wordsLabel?.text = projectNameFirst[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel?.text = projectLst.NameEN
    cell.colorViewOutlet.backgroundColor = .random

    return cell
}
```

Comment: please be clear.

Comment: Can you share your JSON and code ..

Comment: How is the *first letter* related to the name? In the image it seems there is no relationship.

Answer (score 0):

To get first character from string use below code

```
let str = "\(projectLst.NameEN)"
var result = ""
if str.characters.count > 0{
  result = String(str.characters.prefix(1)) // which will return your first charcter
 } else {
  result = "" // result will be empty if string is empty
 }
 cell.wordsLabel?.text = result
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: ganesh but when i attach result value to my tableview cell label xcode giving me this type of error "subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the " what can i do now?

Comment: updated according to your need check it hope that will solve your issue

Comment: ganesh when i attach result label cell " cell.wordsLabel?.text = result[indexPath.row] " ,**xcode give me error  'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion** ..

Comment: you need to set result value to label and result will be string not array answer updated check it once

Comment: i'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  let stringInput = "Ramu"
  let stringInputArr = stringInput.components(separatedBy: " ")
  var stringNeed = ""

  for string in stringInputArr {
       stringNeed = stringNeed + String(string.characters.first!)
  }

  print(stringNeed)
```

Comment: ganesh when i attach result label cell " cell.wordsLabel?.text = result[indexPath.row] " ,**xcode give me error 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion**